# How to convert a ByteArrayOutputStream into a PDF and save in hard disk in Java?

Tags: java, pdf

How to convert a ByteArrayOutputStream into a PDF and save in hard disk in Java?
Please give a sampple.

Comment: That depends entirely on what's in the BAOS.  You didn't specify.

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean by "convert a ByteArrayOutputStream into a PDF"? A ByteArrayOutputStream containing PDF data that you wanna write on disk? Then maybe something like that :

```
String filename = "c:\\test.pdf";
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
output.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
output.close();
```

Comment: assuming that whatever is writing to that BAOS has finished doing that at this point.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF is a binary object so treat it like a JPEG or image file. Do not treat it like a text file or you will break it.